# Pywin32 COM objects passed to function cause pywintypes.com_error

Tags: python, excel, pywin32, win32com

update: see bottom of post

I'm having a small issue with a function designed to create a new workbook in excel, copy all of the data from a passed in sheet to the separate workbook, and then save the workbook.

So, I have the function coded below and for some reason the line:

```
sheet.Range(sheet.Cells(1, 1), sheet.Cells(row_count, max_col)).Copy()
```

throws the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "reports-script.py", line 191, in <module>
format(workbook_filename, query_list, data, colu
mn_orderings)
File "reports-script.py", line 168, in format
excel.save_all_in_workbook_as_mht()
File ".....\excel.py", line 381, in save_all
_as_mht
filename = self.save_copy_as_mht(sheet, sheet.Name, self.folde
r_name)
File ".....\excel_class.py", line 359, in save_cop
y_as_mht
self.excel.Workbooks(1).Sheets(sheet.Name).Cells(row_count, max_col)
File ".....\win32com\client\dynamic.py",
line 172, in __call__
return self._get_good_object_(self._oleobj_.Invoke(*allArgs),self._olerepr_.
defaultDispatchName,None)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None,
 0, -2147352571), 2)
```

I printed the passed in sheet object, and it showed as:

```
<COMObject <unknown>>
```

But I was able to retrieve the Name of the sheet by simply accessing the Name attribute

```
sheet.Name
```

So, I'm not sure if that is a part of the issue I'm seeing or not.

Here is the full function body.

```
def save_copy_as_mht(self, sheet, the_filename, max_col):    
    self.excel.workbooks.Add()
    num_workbooks = self.excel.Workbooks.Count
    #Count occupied rows
    row_count = self.__count_used_rows(sheet, cutoff_number = -1)
    #copy and paste the rows into the new sheet
    sheet.Range(sheet.Cells(1, 1), sheet.Cells(row_count, max_col)).Copy()
    self.excel.Workbooks(num_workbooks).Sheets(1).PasteSpecial()
    self.excel.Workbooks(num_workbooks).Sheets(1).PasteSpecial(XL_PASTE_COLUMN_WIDTHS)
    #Saves the new worksheet using the Query Name, overwrites any existing copies
    self.save_workbook_as_mht(self.excel.Workbooks(num_workbooks), the_filename, self.folder_name)
    #Close workbook
    self.excel.Workbooks(num_workbooks).Close()
```

I realize there are two function calls above whose code I have not posted, but execution does not even reach that far in the function for one of them, and the other one simply returns an integer.

Thanks!

UPDATE: Alright well it would appear that if I replace the variable references "row_count" and "max_col" with hard-coded integers that everything works just fine.....but that doesn't really solve my problem it just diagnoses it more clearly. Why would COM function calls fail when passed python variables? And how can I fix this??

Comment: well, I have no idea what is going wrong in the code per se, but if you can't debug it might I suggest you use a python specific excel writer like `openpyxl` http://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/?  The few time I've tried to use excel from python through pywin32 I've had no success either...

Comment: It's a bit late....I've already got 95% of the code for my application going. And I think if I did some messy weird coding I could get this to work. But I'd rather get it working for reasons I understand.

I do appreciate the tip however!

Comment: UPDATE: Alright well it would appear that if I replace the variable references "row_count" and "max_col" with hard-coded integers that everything works just fine.....but that doesn't really solve my problem it just diagnoses it more clearly. Why would COM function calls fail when passed python variables? And how can I fix this??

Comment: Sounds like a type issue. Do you explicitly have to "cast" the python variables as the type the Excel call is expecting?